How to properly close a QWidget created on an other thread? [OBS Source Plugin]
I am trying to make a plugin for OBS Studio that will add a custom source type object.
OBS provide a simple way to let the user display and change the source properties with the function get_properties(), but sadly this is not enough for my plugin. Instead, I create a whole new QWidget as my source properties main window and close the default one opened by OBS studio.
More precisely, I am doing the following:

When get_properties() is called by the source, it will create a new GUIHandler if not already existing and call GUIHandler::show().
GUIHandler::show() will close the QWidget created by OBS Studio (I use QApplication::topLevelWindows() to find it) and then will create and show my custom OBSGraphicsMainWindow (inherited from QWidget).

Of course, my OBSGraphicsMainWindow access to some variables stored in my source object in order to read and write some values.
So far everything is working fine, but the problems begin when I need to delete my window. Basically, there are three scenarios that delete the window:

When the user click on the OBSGraphicsMainWindow close button.
When the user removes the source from the scene and the OBSGraphicsMainWindow linked to it was opened.
When OBS Studio is closed (i.e.: the user presses on the OBS Studio main window close button) and OBSGraphicsMainWindow were opened.

The first option is not a problem, but I cannot find a good way to delete my window in the GUIHandler destructor, which will be called anytime the source is destroyed.
This is how I am doing so far:
GUIHandler::~GUIHandler()
{
    if (window != nullptr) {
        window->onDeletion = nullptr;
        window->deleteLater();
    }
}

This is kind of working, but the problem is that deleteLater() will delete the OBSGraphicsMainWindow in a non thread-safe implementation, and sometimes it will try to access source object variables that are already deleted, which might make OBS crash.
I would prefer to use delete window; instead, but for what I have understand I cannot do it because my OBSGraphicsMainWindow QWidget was not created on the same thread as OBS Studio QWidget. Because of that, the destroyed() signal will be emitted by the OBS Studio thread, but the receiver is my source thread, which is not allowed in Qt:
ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread. Current thread 0x0x2807a1a5060. Receiver '' (of type 'QWidget') was created in thread 0x0x2807457c590"
If I try to use window->close() instead, the program hangs forever and freeze.

QUESTION: What do you think is the best way to delete my custom OBSGraphicsMainWindow QWidget object created in another thread when it needed to be closed from the OBS Studio main thread ? Should I use deleteLater() with a std::mutex shared by both threads, and make the thread wait for the deletion of all Qt object before deleting my source object ? I must not change the OBS Studio code itself.
Thanks in advance for your answers!
EDIT:
I changed the GUIHandler destructor. Here is the class:

.h:

#pragma once
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>

class OBSGraphicsMainWindow;
class OBSBlueprintGraph;

class GUIHandler {
public:

    GUIHandler(OBSBlueprintGraph* g);
    ~GUIHandler();

    void show() const;

private:

    std::condition_variable cond{};

    OBSGraphicsMainWindow* window = nullptr;
    OBSBlueprintGraph* graph;


.cpp:

#include "gui-graph.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QScreen>
#include <QWindow>

#include "obs-frontend-api.h"
#include "obs-graphics-main-window.h"
#include "Core/obs-blueprint-graph.h"
#include "Helpers/global-logger.h"


GUIHandler::GUIHandler(OBSBlueprintGraph *g) : graph(g)
{
    QWidget *parent = static_cast<QWidget *>(obs_frontend_get_main_window());
    window = new OBSGraphicsMainWindow(graph, parent, Qt::Window | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
    window->deleteComplete = [this] {
        GDebug("[GUI] >> Main Window DESTROYED! <<");
        window = nullptr;
        cond.notify_all();
    };
}

GUIHandler::~GUIHandler()
{
    if (window != nullptr) {
        std::mutex mtx{};
        std::unique_lock lock{mtx};
        window->deleteLater();
        cond.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(100)); // TODO improve this. For now GUI is still deleted AFTER graph if closed
        if (window != nullptr) {
            window->context().onDeletion.execute();
        }
    }
}


void GUIHandler::show() const
{
    // Hide default OBS properties window, TODO how to do it better? maybe even prevent properties window creation?
    const QWindowList list = QApplication::topLevelWindows();

    // Reverse list loop for better performance
    QList<QWindow*>::const_iterator it = list.constEnd();
    while(it != list.constBegin()) {
        --it;
        if((*it)->objectName() == "OBSBasicPropertiesWindow") {
            (*it)->close();
            break;
        }
    }

    window->adjustSize(); // Size to content

    // Center window on screen
    QRect screenRect = QApplication::primaryScreen()->geometry();
    QRect windowRect = window->geometry();
    window->move((screenRect.width() - windowRect.width())/2, (screenRect.height() - windowRect.height())/2);
    window->show();
}

The std::function<void()> deleteComplete is called when the OBSGraphicsMainWindow have deleted all his child QObjects.

This all makes so little sense to me... 1. QWidget are to be created only in the main thread (aka GUI thread), 2. deleteLater simply deletes an object when the thread it lives in returns to the event loop (for QWidget, that is the main thread again); when an object is deleted, it indeed deletes its children but the children of an object are to live in the same thread as their parents (which is why moveToThread cannot be called on an object with a parent)

I do not quite see a situation where you would want to delete an object from a thread it does not live in while, at the same time, calling deleteLater on one of its ancestor. I acknowledge providing a minimal reproducible example may be challenging in your case but without that, the above remarks will cause experienced Qt developers to be puzzled by what you are describing and most likely unable to answer.

I don't know how OBS is internally implemented, but I would be quite surprised if it created widgets in different threads, since that's normally not possible: as most GUI related classes, widgets can only be created in the main application thread, and cannot live (or be moved) in different threads. The fact that you're able to use QApplication::topLevelWindows() (QWindows also can only exist in the main thread) and access them confirms that. Are you sure you're not accessing objects in a non thread-safe way? To what object does the destroyed signal refer? How is it connected?

Thanks for your responses. I agree that it is not easy to explain my issue, so I will try to explain it an other way:

I, personally, do not create any thread in my own code. I assumed that OBS handle sources lifecycle using multithreading, but it might not be the case.
OBS Studio implemented a global handler to recieve all QEvent::Show events. You can see the code here, line 1406. I got the assertion threading error on line 1437.
Here is the code of my project: https://github.com/bukibarak/obs-blueprint


I think I was able to solve my problem using a condition_variable combined with the OBS Frontend API callbacks!
As mentionned before, I can't simply use delete window; in the ~GUIHandler() destructor because then I would get the following error when the destructor is called through obs_source_info destroy() function ptr:
ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread. Current thread 0x0x2807a1a5060. Receiver '' (of type 'QWidget') was created in thread 0x0x2807457c590"
In order to use deleteLater() and wait for the OBSGraphicsMainWindow deletion, I implemented a condition_variable that will wait right after deleteLater() has been called. On the other side, when the OBSGraphicsMainWindow is deleted, the condition_variable will be notified.
This was working well when deleting the OBS source from the scene, but will make the program hangs forever and freeze if the program was closed. After looking a bit more into OBS Studio, I find out that the OBS Frontent API send an event of type OBS_FRONTEND_EVENT_SCRIPTING_SHUTDOWN before sources are destroyed (see OBSBasic::closeEvent(), line 4879). Because OBS Frontend API uses Qt thread, I was able to add a callback to the event and directly delete the OBSGraphicsMainWindow using delete window;.

obs-graphics-main-window.h:
class OBSGraphicsMainWindow : public QWidget {
public:
    OBSGraphicsMainWindow(OBSBlueprintGraph* g, QWidget *parent = nullptr, Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags());
    ~OBSGraphicsMainWindow() override;

    std::function<void()> onDestructorEnd;

private:
    ...
};

obs-graphics-main-window.cpp:
OBSGraphicsMainWindow::OBSGraphicsMainWindow(OBSBlueprintGraph *g, QWidget *parent, Qt::WindowFlags f)
    : QWidget(parent, f), graph(g)
{
    ...
}

OBSGraphicsMainWindow::~OBSGraphicsMainWindow()
{
    delete layout;
    ...
    if (onDestructorEnd)
        onDestructorEnd();
}

gui-handler.h:
class GUIHandler {
public:

    GUIHandler(OBSBlueprintGraph* g);
    ~GUIHandler();

    static void OBSEvent(enum obs_frontend_event event, void* ptr);
    void show() const;

private:

    std::condition_variable cond{};

    OBSGraphicsMainWindow* window = nullptr;
    OBSBlueprintGraph* graph;
};

gui-handler.cpp:
GUIHandler::GUIHandler(OBSBlueprintGraph *g) : graph(g)
{
    obs_frontend_add_event_callback(OBSEvent, this);
    QWidget *parent = static_cast<QWidget *>(obs_frontend_get_main_window());
    window = new OBSGraphicsMainWindow(graph, parent, Qt::Window | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
    window->onDestructorEnd = [this] {
        GDebug("[GUI] OBS Blueprint main window Destroyed!");
        window = nullptr;
        cond.notify_all();
    };
}

GUIHandler::~GUIHandler()
{
    obs_frontend_remove_event_callback(OBSEvent, this);
    if (window != nullptr) {
        GDebug("[GUI] Destroy OBS BP Main window using deleteLater() and lock");
        std::mutex mtx{};
        std::unique_lock lock{mtx};
        window->deleteLater();
        cond.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

void GUIHandler::OBSEvent(enum obs_frontend_event event, void *ptr)
{
    if (event == OBS_FRONTEND_EVENT_SCRIPTING_SHUTDOWN) {
        GDebug("[GUI] Destroy OBS BP Main window using OBS Frontend API Event");
        GUIHandler *handler = static_cast<GUIHandler *>(ptr);
        delete handler->window;
    }
}


void GUIHandler::show() const
{
    // Hide default OBS properties window, TODO how to do it better? maybe even prevent properties window creation?
    const QWindowList list = QApplication::topLevelWindows();

    // Reverse list loop for better performance
    QList<QWindow*>::const_iterator it = list.constEnd();
    while(it != list.constBegin()) {
        --it;
        if((*it)->objectName() == "OBSBasicPropertiesWindow") {
            (*it)->close();
            break;
        }
    }

    window->adjustSize(); // Size to content

    // Center window on screen
    QRect screenRect = QApplication::primaryScreen()->geometry();
    QRect windowRect = window->geometry();
    window->move((screenRect.width() - windowRect.width())/2, (screenRect.height() - windowRect.height())/2);
    window->show();
}

